# getDb()->createCommand - заменяет фигурную скобку на обратную ковычку

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Достаточно нестандартная проблема, хочу записать строку такого вида
"... {\frac{{5}} ..." в базу, построитель запросов заменяет некоторые скобки на `  (обратная ковычка)

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET text = (CASE id  WHEN 123 THEN '<p><p>{\frac{{5}}{x}}}$$.</p></p>'  END) WHERE id IN(123)";
$raw = Task::getDb()->createCommand($upQuery)->getRawSql();
```

На выходе в $raw лежит это, ( обращаем внимание на фрагмент \frac{`5`} )

```
UPDATE table SET text = (CASE id  WHEN 123 THEN '<p><p>{\frac{`5`}{x}}}$$.</p></p>'  END) WHERE id IN(123)
```

Как это обойти? Нужно как-то экранировать скобки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
use yii\db\Expression;

$query = "UPDATE table 
          SET text = (CASE id  
                      WHEN 123 THEN '".new Expression('<p><p>{\frac{{5}}{x}}}$$.</p></p>')."'  
                      END) 
          WHERE id IN(123)";
```

Из мануала [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression]

> Expression represents a DB expression that does not need escaping or quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Можно дернуть напрямую, тогда улетит чистый raw sql в базу.
Но это небезопасно как я понял

`Model::getDb()->getMasterPdo()->exec($query);`